# Windows Phone 7.1 Mango and compatibility

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Coming from the iOS world, I had a "build target" that I could set for say, iOS 4.0, so any OS including 4.0 and above that will be able to launch the app.

For the case of Mango, is it possible to do the same ? Can I build a .xap that will be able to launch on both Windows Phone 7.0 and Windows Phone 7.1 ? If so, what are the good techniques used to check for SDK availability (something like `respondsToSelector`)

If not, what will happen for a compiled-for-mango app in the Marketplace of a 7.0 user ? The app just won't show up ? Or show a message "You need to update your phone" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be targeted for "Mango", if you want it showing on both markets you'll have to backport stuff into a 7.0 project.

Comment: about "backport stuff" learn here: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Switching-between-Windows-Phone-7-1-Mango-and-7-0-RTW-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 2):

There's a compatibility chart at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202996(v=VS.92).aspx